# How to stream data sorted from a table in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, query-performance

I am trying to get the data from a PostgreSQL table in sorted order using Java. The problem lies in the query planning of PostgreSQL - have a look at these queries:

```
select *
from the_table
order by the_indexed_column asc
;
```

The query plan for this is:

```
Gather Merge  (cost=16673025.39..28912422.53 rows=104901794 width=64)
  Workers Planned: 2
  ->  Sort  (cost=16672025.36..16803152.60 rows=52450897 width=64)
        Sort Key: "time"
        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on raw  (cost=0.00..4030550.63 rows=52450897 width=64)
```

The `Sort` at the top prevents the streaming of the data, because it must aggregate the data first. This is problematic for sorts with large amounts of data, e.g. 20GB in my case as they have to be saved to disk.

Compare this query:

```
select *
from raw
order by the_index_column asc
limit 10000000
;
```

Plan:

```
Limit  (cost=0.57..9871396.70 rows=10000000 width=64)
  ->  Index Scan using raw_time_idx on raw  (cost=0.57..124263259.38 rows=125882152 width=64)
```

This data can be easily streamed.

I think PostgreSQL only optimizes for total query speed here, not for additional features like disk usage and streaming capabilities. Is there a way to tune PostgreSQL to choose the second plan in favour of the first?

**EDIT:**
This the code for the execution of the query. The string at the end is not printed.

```
Connection database = DriverManager.getConnection(DatabaseConstants.DATABASE_URL, DatabaseConstants.USER, DatabaseConstants.PASSWORD);
String sql = "select " +
                "column_a, column_b, some_expression, morestuff " +
                "from the_table " +
                "order by the_indexed_column asc " +
                ";";
database.setAutoCommit(false);
PreparedStatement statement = database.prepareStatement(sql);
statement.setFetchSize(1024);
ResultSet set = statement.executeQuery();
System.out.println("Got first results...");
```

The value of `cursor_tuple_fraction` was lowered to 0.05, 0.01 and 0.0 with no effect.

PostgreSQL Version: 10.7, 
Driver Version: 42.2.5.jre7 (the most recent in Maven (now for real)),
OS: Fedora 29 (Minimal with KDE on top)

This is the output on the log with `log_min_duration_statement = 0`:

```
2019-03-29 17:11:52.532 CET [15068] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2019-03-29 17:12:04.615 CET [15119] LOG:  duration: 0.397 ms  parse <unnamed>: SET extra_float_digits = 3
2019-03-29 17:12:04.615 CET [15119] LOG:  duration: 0.008 ms  bind <unnamed>: SET extra_float_digits = 3
2019-03-29 17:12:04.615 CET [15119] LOG:  duration: 0.046 ms  execute <unnamed>: SET extra_float_digits = 3
2019-03-29 17:12:04.615 CET [15119] LOG:  duration: 0.024 ms  parse <unnamed>: SET application_name = 'PostgreSQL JDBC Driver'
2019-03-29 17:12:04.615 CET [15119] LOG:  duration: 0.006 ms  bind <unnamed>: SET application_name = 'PostgreSQL JDBC Driver'
2019-03-29 17:12:04.615 CET [15119] LOG:  duration: 0.026 ms  execute <unnamed>: SET application_name = 'PostgreSQL JDBC Driver'
2019-03-29 17:12:04.662 CET [15119] LOG:  duration: 0.023 ms  parse <unnamed>: BEGIN
2019-03-29 17:12:04.662 CET [15119] LOG:  duration: 0.006 ms  bind <unnamed>: BEGIN
2019-03-29 17:12:04.662 CET [15119] LOG:  duration: 0.004 ms  execute <unnamed>: BEGIN
2019-03-29 17:12:04.940 CET [15119] LOG:  duration: 277.705 ms  parse <unnamed>: [the query...] 
2019-03-29 17:12:05.162 CET [15119] LOG:  duration: 222.742 ms  bind <unnamed>/C_1: [the query...]
```

During this, the disk usage increases.

Comment: Unrelated, but: `9.1-901-1.jdbc4` is **horribly** outdated. The current [driver version](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/) is 42.2.5 which is also available on [Maven Central](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:org.postgresql)

Comment: Oh, I was only looking for versions of the package postgresql of group postgresql. Did not notice that the current group is org.postgresql. Updated the driver with no effect.

Answer (score 1):

That shouldn't be a problem. Use a cursor by applying `setFetchSize` with a non-zero value to the prepared statement.

Then PostgreSQL will choose a plan that returns the first rows quickly, that is an index scan.

If PostgreSQL still chooses a sort, lower `cursor_tuple_fraction` from its default value of 0.1 (10% of the total result set).

For the record: This is how it should look in the log:

```
duration: 0.126 ms  parse S_1: BEGIN
duration: 0.015 ms  bind S_1: BEGIN
duration: 0.034 ms  execute S_1: BEGIN
duration: 0.998 ms  parse S_2: SELECT /* the query */
duration: 1.752 ms  bind S_2/C_3: SELECT /* the query */
duration: 0.081 ms  execute S_2/C_3: SELECT /* the query */
duration: 0.060 ms  execute fetch from S_2/C_3: SELECT /* the query */
duration: 0.065 ms  execute fetch from S_2/C_3: SELECT /* the query */
duration: 0.070 ms  execute fetch from S_2/C_3: SELECT /* the query */
duration: 0.078 ms  execute fetch from S_2/C_3: SELECT /* the query */
```

Comment: Added information to my question, as your solution did not work for me :/

Comment: Can you set `log_min_duration_statement = 0` in `postgresql.conf` and see what is logged?

Comment: Log entries added.

Comment: I have added how the log entries should look. Do you see no `execute` messages for the query?

Comment: This is all I see after 10 minutes (on a recent laptop).

Comment: Hard to believe with very low `cursor_tuple_fraction`. If the table is *that* large, and you want to get the whole thing, the sort is probably really cheaper. If you don't want the whole table, use `LIMIT`. Sorting becomes faster with large `work_mem`.